# can I just get Scala REPL without creating a project using sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

I want to install `Scala` `REPL` on `windows10`. I looked around on internet but I can't seem to find how I can just get `scala` binaries and `REPL`. The links seem to suggest that I either use `Intellij` or `sbt`. If I get sbt, the way to create a project is eg `sbt new hello` which seem to be doing a lot of stuff (see below)!

Question 1 - How can I get just `REPL`. I don't want to create projects, I just need a command line tool to practice writing expressions.

Question 2- After installing `sbt`, I did `sbt new hello` and I was overwhelmed to see the result in the command line. What is `sbt` doing below and why the project still wasn't created (see the error in the end, `Template not found for: hello`? I have truncated the output to stay within the word limit

```
C:\Users\manuc\Documents\manu>mkdir scala_programs

C:\Users\manuc\Documents\manu>cd scala_programs

C:\Users\manuc\Documents\manu\scala_programs>sbt new hello
"about to robocopy"

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : 14 September 2018 09:43:43
   Source : C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\
     Dest : C:\Users\manuc\.sbt\preloaded\

    Files : *.*

  Options : *.* /S /E /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

          New Dir          0    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\
          New Dir          0    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.eed3si9n\
          New Dir          0    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.eed3si9n\gigahorse-core_2.12\
          New Dir          0    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.eed3si9n\gigahorse-core_2.12\0.3.0\
          New Dir          3    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.eed3si9n\gigahorse-core_2.12\0.3.0\ivys\
100%        New File                3160        ivy.xml
100%        New File                  32        ivy.xml.md5
100%        New File                  40        ivy.xml.sha1
          New Dir          3    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.eed3si9n\gigahorse-core_2.12\0.3.0\jars\
100%        New File              166989        gigahorse-core_2.12.jar
100%        New File                  32        gigahorse-core_2.12.jar.md5
100%        New File                  40        gigahorse-core_2.12.jar.sha1
          New Dir          0    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.eed3si9n\gigahorse-okhttp_2.12\
          New Dir          0    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.eed3si9n\gigahorse-okhttp_2.12\0.3.0\
          New Dir          3    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.eed3si9n\gigahorse-okhttp_2.12\0.3.0\ivys\
100%        New File                3021        ivy.xml
100%        New File                  32        ivy.xml.md5
100%        New File                  40        ivy.xml.sha1
          New Dir          3    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.eed3si9n\gigahorse-okhttp_2.12\0.3.0\jars\
100%        New File               40267        gigahorse-okhttp_2.12.jar
100%        New File                  32        gigahorse-okhttp_2.12.jar.md5
100%        New File                  40        gigahorse-okhttp_2.12.jar.sha1
          New Dir          0    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.eed3si9n\shaded-scalajson_2.12\
          New Dir          0    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.eed3si9n\shaded-scalajson_2.12\1.0.0-M4\
          New Dir          3    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.eed3si9n\shaded-scalajson_2.12\1.0.0-M4\ivys\
100%        New File                2943        ivy.xml
100%        New File                  32        ivy.xml.md5
100%        New File                  40        ivy.xml.sha1
          New Dir          3    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.eed3si9n\shaded-scalajson_2.12\1.0.0-M4\jars\
100%        New File               66051        shaded-scalajson_2.12.jar
100%        New File                  32        shaded-scalajson_2.12.jar.md5
100%        New File                  40        shaded-scalajson_2.12.jar.sha1
          New Dir          0    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.eed3si9n\sjson-new-core_2.12\
          New Dir          0    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.eed3si9n\sjson-new-core_2.12\0.8.2\
          New Dir          3    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.eed3si9n\sjson-new-core_2.12\0.8.2\ivys\
100%        New File                3076        ivy.xml
100%        New File                  32        ivy.xml.md5
100%        New File                  40        ivy.xml.sha1
          New Dir          3    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.eed3si9n\sjson-new-core_2.12\0.8.2\jars\
100%        New File              786619        sjson-new-core_2.12.jar
100%        New File                  32        sjson-new-core_2.12.jar.md5
100%        New File                  40        sjson-new-core_2.12.jar.sha1
          New Dir          0    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.eed3si9n\sjson-new-murmurhash_2.12\
          New Dir          0    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.eed3si9n\sjson-new-murmurhash_2.12\0.8.2\
          New Dir          3    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.eed3si9n\sjson-new-murmurhash_2.12\0.8.2\ivys\
100%        New File                3233        ivy.xml
100%        New File                  32        ivy.xml.md5
100%        New File                  40        ivy.xml.sha1
          New Dir          3    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.eed3si9n\sjson-new-murmurhash_2.12\0.8.2\jars\
100%        New File                5265        sjson-new-murmurhash_2.12.jar
100%        New File                  32        sjson-new-murmurhash_2.12.jar.md5
100%        New File                  40        sjson-new-murmurhash_2.12.jar.sha1
          New Dir          0    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.eed3si9n\sjson-new-scalajson_2.12\
          New Dir          0    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.eed3si9n\sjson-new-scalajson_2.12\0.8.2\
          New Dir          3    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.eed3si9n\sjson-new-scalajson_2.12\0.8.2\ivys\
100%        New File                3526        ivy.xml
100%        New File                  32        ivy.xml.md5
100%        New File                  40        ivy.xml.sha1
          New Dir          3    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.eed3si9n\sjson-new-scalajson_2.12\0.8.2\jars\
100%        New File               37200        sjson-new-scalajson_2.12.jar
100%        New File                  32        sjson-new-scalajson_2.12.jar.md5
100%        New File                  40        sjson-new-scalajson_2.12.jar.sha1
          New Dir          0    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.github.ben-manes.caffeine\
          New Dir          0    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.github.ben-manes.caffeine\caffeine\
          New Dir          0    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.github.ben-manes.caffeine\caffeine\2.5.6\
          New Dir          3    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.github.ben-manes.caffeine\caffeine\2.5.6\ivys\
100%        New File                5654        ivy.xml
100%        New File                  32        ivy.xml.md5
100%        New File                  40        ivy.xml.sha1
          New Dir          3    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.github.ben-manes.caffeine\caffeine\2.5.6\jars\
100%        New File             1007139        caffeine.jar
100%        New File                  32        caffeine.jar.md5
100%        New File                  40        caffeine.jar.sha1
          New Dir          0    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.github.cb372\
          New Dir          0    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.github.cb372\scalacache-caffeine_2.12\
          New Dir          0    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.github.cb372\scalacache-caffeine_2.12\0.20.0\
          New Dir          3    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.github.cb372\scalacache-caffeine_2.12\0.20.0\ivys\
100%        New File                3460        ivy.xml
100%        New File                  32        ivy.xml.md5
100%        New File                  40        ivy.xml.sha1
          New Dir          3    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.github.cb372\scalacache-caffeine_2.12\0.20.0\jars\
100%        New File                7023        scalacache-caffeine_2.12.jar
100%        New File                  32        scalacache-caffeine_2.12.jar.md5
100%        New File                  40        scalacache-caffeine_2.12.jar.sha1
          New Dir          0    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.github.cb372\scalacache-core_2.12\
          New Dir          0    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.github.cb372\scalacache-core_2.12\0.20.0\
          New Dir          3    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.github.cb372\scalacache-core_2.12\0.20.0\ivys\
100%        New File                3255        ivy.xml
100%        New File                  32        ivy.xml.md5
100%        New File                  40        ivy.xml.sha1
          New Dir          3    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.github.cb372\scalacache-core_2.12\0.20.0\jars\
100%        New File              124718        scalacache-core_2.12.jar
100%        New File                  32        scalacache-core_2.12.jar.md5
100%        New File                  40        scalacache-core_2.12.jar.sha1
          New Dir          0    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.google.protobuf\
          New Dir          0    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.google.protobuf\protobuf-java\
          New Dir          0    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.google.protobuf\protobuf-java\3.3.1\
          New Dir          3    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.google.protobuf\protobuf-java\3.3.1\bundles\
100%        New File               1.2 m        protobuf-java.jar
100%        New File                  32        protobuf-java.jar.md5
100%        New File                  40        protobuf-java.jar.sha1
          New Dir          3    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.google.protobuf\protobuf-java\3.3.1\ivys\
100%        New File                5219        ivy.xml
100%        New File                  32        ivy.xml.md5
100%        New File                  40        ivy.xml.sha1
          New Dir          0    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.jcraft\
          New Dir          0    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.jcraft\jsch\
          New Dir          0    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.jcraft\jsch\0.1.54\
          New Dir          3    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.jcraft\jsch\0.1.54\ivys\
100%        New File                3271        ivy.xml
100%        New File                  32        ivy.xml.md5
100%        New File                  40        ivy.xml.sha1
          New Dir          3    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.jcraft\jsch\0.1.54\jars\
100%        New File              280515        jsch.jar
100%        New File                  32        jsch.jar.md5
100%        New File                  40        jsch.jar.sha1
          New Dir          0    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.lihaoyi\
          New Dir          0    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.lihaoyi\fastparse-utils_2.12\
          New Dir          0    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.lihaoyi\fastparse-utils_2.12\0.4.2\
          New Dir          3    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.lihaoyi\fastparse-utils_2.12\0.4.2\ivys\
100%        New File                3266        ivy.xml
100%        New File                  32        ivy.xml.md5
100%        New File                  40        ivy.xml.sha1
          New Dir          3    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.lihaoyi\fastparse-utils_2.12\0.4.2\jars\
100%        New File               62230        fastparse-utils_2.12.jar
100%        New File                  32        fastparse-utils_2.12.jar.md5
100%        New File                  40        fastparse-utils_2.12.jar.sha1
          New Dir          0    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.lihaoyi\fastparse_2.12\
          New Dir          0    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.lihaoyi\fastparse_2.12\0.4.2\
          New Dir          3    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.lihaoyi\fastparse_2.12\0.4.2\ivys\
100%        New File                3393        ivy.xml
100%        New File                  32        ivy.xml.md5
100%        New File                  40        ivy.xml.sha1
          New Dir          3    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.lihaoyi\fastparse_2.12\0.4.2\jars\
100%        New File              306991        fastparse_2.12.jar
100%        New File                  32        fastparse_2.12.jar.md5
100%        New File                  40        fastparse_2.12.jar.sha1
          New Dir          0    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.lihaoyi\sourcecode_2.12\
          New Dir          0    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.lihaoyi\sourcecode_2.12\0.1.3\
          New Dir          3    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.lihaoyi\sourcecode_2.12\0.1.3\ivys\
100%        New File                2856        ivy.xml
100%        New File                  32        ivy.xml.md5
100%        New File                  40        ivy.xml.sha1
          New Dir          3    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.lihaoyi\sourcecode_2.12\0.1.3\jars\
100%        New File              110534        sourcecode_2.12.jar
100%        New File                  32        sourcecode_2.12.jar.md5
100%        New File                  40        sourcecode_2.12.jar.sha1
          New Dir          0    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.lmax\
          New Dir          0    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.lmax\disruptor\
          New Dir          0    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.lmax\disruptor\3.3.6\
          New Dir          3    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.lmax\disruptor\3.3.6\ivys\
100%        New File                2792        ivy.xml
100%        New File                  32        ivy.xml.md5
100%        New File                  40        ivy.xml.sha1
          New Dir          3    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.lmax\disruptor\3.3.6\jars\
100%        New File               84123        disruptor.jar
100%        New File                  32        disruptor.jar.md5
100%        New File                  40        disruptor.jar.sha1
          New Dir          0    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.squareup.okhttp3\
          New Dir          0    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.squareup.okhttp3\okhttp\
          New Dir          0    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.squareup.okhttp3\okhttp\3.7.0\
          New Dir          3    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.squareup.okhttp3\okhttp\3.7.0\ivys\
100%        New File                6067        ivy.xml
100%        New File                  32        ivy.xml.md5
100%        New File                  40        ivy.xml.sha1
          New Dir          3    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.squareup.okhttp3\okhttp\3.7.0\jars\
100%        New File              394987        okhttp.jar
100%        New File                  32        okhttp.jar.md5
100%        New File                  40        okhttp.jar.sha1
          New Dir          0    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.squareup.okhttp3\okhttp-urlconnection\
          New Dir          0    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.squareup.okhttp3\okhttp-urlconnection\3.7.0\
          New Dir          3    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.squareup.okhttp3\okhttp-urlconnection\3.7.0\ivys\
100%        New File                6392        ivy.xml
100%        New File                  32        ivy.xml.md5
100%        New File                  40        ivy.xml.sha1
          New Dir          3    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.squareup.okhttp3\okhttp-urlconnection\3.7.0\jars\
100%        New File               32607        okhttp-urlconnection.jar
100%        New File                  32        okhttp-urlconnection.jar.md5
100%        New File                  40        okhttp-urlconnection.jar.sha1
          New Dir          0    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.squareup.okio\
          New Dir          0    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.squareup.okio\okio\
          New Dir          0    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.squareup.okio\okio\1.12.0\
          New Dir          3    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.squareup.okio\okio\1.12.0\ivys\
100%        New File                4513        ivy.xml
100%        New File                  32        ivy.xml.md5
100%        New File                  40        ivy.xml.sha1
          New Dir          3    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.squareup.okio\okio\1.12.0\jars\
100%        New File               81088        okio.jar
100%        New File                  32        okio.jar.md5
100%        New File                  40        okio.jar.sha1
          New Dir          0    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.swoval\
          New Dir          0    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.swoval\apple-file-events\
          New Dir          0    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.swoval\apple-file-events\1.3.2\
          New Dir          3    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.swoval\apple-file-events\1.3.2\ivys\
100%        New File                3089        ivy.xml
100%        New File                  32        ivy.xml.md5
100%        New File                  40        ivy.xml.sha1
          New Dir          3    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.swoval\apple-file-events\1.3.2\jars\
100%        New File               23033        apple-file-events.jar
100%        New File                  32        apple-file-events.jar.md5
100%        New File                  40        apple-file-events.jar.sha1
          New Dir          0    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.trueaccord.lenses\
          New Dir          0    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.trueaccord.lenses\lenses_2.12\
          New Dir          0    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.trueaccord.lenses\lenses_2.12\0.4.12\
          New Dir          3    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.trueaccord.lenses\lenses_2.12\0.4.12\ivys\
100%        New File                2793        ivy.xml
100%        New File                  32        ivy.xml.md5
100%        New File                  40        ivy.xml.sha1
          New Dir          3    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.trueaccord.lenses\lenses_2.12\0.4.12\jars\
100%        New File               33920        lenses_2.12.jar
100%        New File                  32        lenses_2.12.jar.md5
100%        New File                  40        lenses_2.12.jar.sha1
          New Dir          0    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.trueaccord.scalapb\
          New Dir          0    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.trueaccord.scalapb\scalapb-runtime_2.12\
          New Dir          0    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.trueaccord.scalapb\scalapb-runtime_2.12\0.6.0\
          New Dir          3    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\com.trueaccord.scalapb\scalapb-runtime_2.12\0.6.0\ivys\

100%        New File               1.0 m        ivy.jar
100%        New File                  32        ivy.jar.md5
100%        New File                  40        ivy.jar.sha1
          New Dir          0    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\org.slf4j\
          New Dir          0    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\org.slf4j\slf4j-api\
          New Dir          0    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\org.slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.25\
          New Dir          3    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\org.slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.25\ivys\
100%        New File                5340        ivy.xml
100%        New File                  32        ivy.xml.md5
100%        New File                  40        ivy.xml.sha1
          New Dir          3    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\org.slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.25\jars\
100%        New File               41203        slf4j-api.jar
100%        New File                  32        slf4j-api.jar.md5
100%        New File                  40        slf4j-api.jar.sha1
          New Dir          0    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\org.spire-math\
          New Dir          0    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\org.spire-math\jawn-parser_2.12\
          New Dir          0    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\org.spire-math\jawn-parser_2.12\0.10.4\
          New Dir          3    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\org.spire-math\jawn-parser_2.12\0.10.4\ivys\
100%        New File                2769        ivy.xml
100%        New File                  32        ivy.xml.md5
100%        New File                  40        ivy.xml.sha1
          New Dir          3    C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\lib\local-preloaded\org.spire-math\jawn-parser_2.12\0.10.4\jars\
100%        New File               74239        jawn-parser_2.12.jar
100%        New File                  32        jawn-parser_2.12.jar.md5
100%        New File                  40        jawn-parser_2.12.jar.sha1

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

               Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
    Dirs :       364       364         0         0         0         0
   Files :       507       507         0         0         0         0
   Bytes :   49.48 m   49.48 m         0         0         0         0
   Times :   0:00:06   0:00:02                       0:00:00   0:00:04


   Speed :            18593244 Bytes/sec.
   Speed :            1063.913 MegaBytes/min.
   Ended : 14 September 2018 09:43:50

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 1.2.1  (this may take some time)...
downloading file:/C:/Users/manuc/.sbt/preloaded/org.scala-sbt/sbt/1.2.1/jars/sbt.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#sbt;1.2.1!sbt.jar (57ms)
downloading file:/C:/Users/manuc/.sbt/preloaded/org.scala-lang/scala-library/2.12.6/jars/scala-library.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.12.6!scala-library.jar (140ms)
```

...
    Template not found for: hello

```
C:\Users\manuc\Documents\manu\scala_programs>dir
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is 62A2-7F68

 Directory of C:\Users\manuc\Documents\manu\scala_programs

14/09/2018  09:43    <DIR>          .
14/09/2018  09:43    <DIR>          ..
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  118,741,135,360 bytes free

C:\Users\manuc\Documents\manu\scala_programs>
C:\Users\manuc\Documents\manu\scala_programs>
C:\Users\manuc\Documents\manu\scala_programs>dir
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is 62A2-7F68

 Directory of C:\Users\manuc\Documents\manu\scala_programs

14/09/2018  09:43    <DIR>          .
14/09/2018  09:43    <DIR>          ..
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  118,743,207,936 bytes free

C:\Users\manuc\Documents\manu\scala_programs>
```

Comment: did you see this instruction? https://docs.scala-lang.org/getting-started-sbt-track/getting-started-with-scala-and-sbt-on-the-command-line.html

Comment: I did. But for just running `REPL`, it looks like an overkill. I have to get `sbt`, the use a template but I don't want all these extra bits

Comment: if you want "just Scala REPL", you can use it online without any installation, for example here - https://scastie.scala-lang.org

Comment: my first comment was related your `sbt`setup attempt - template name you're using does not look right.

Comment: ok. got it. I think I just got a hang of how to just use `repl` using `Sbt`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The accepted answer is wrong

On the official page https://www.scala-lang.org/download/ there are three ways to get started with scala: **Download Intellij** or **Download SBT**.

Below these options is: **Other ways to install Scala**. The first option is to Download Scala binaries for Windows. You can download, install, add it to the PATH, and 
type `scala` into the command line to start the REPL.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that for scala versions `2.12.6` and below, I can install binaries but for higher versions, either `Intellij` or `sbt` is required. If using `sbt`, just type `sbt` on console, enter `c` for continue, then type `console`. This starts `REPL`.

```
C:\Users\manuc\Documents\manu\scala_programs>sbt
[warn] Neither build.sbt nor a 'project' directory in the current directory: C:\Users\manuc\Documents\manu\scala_programs
c) continue
q) quit
? c
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
[warn] No sbt.version set in project/build.properties, base directory: C:\Users\manuc\Documents\manu\scala_programs
[info] Set current project to scala_programs (in build file:/C:/Users/manuc/Documents/manu/scala_programs/)
[info] sbt server started at local:sbt-server-f91ec751458c99f5d069

sbt:scala_programs> console
[info] Updating ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Non-compiled module 'compiler-bridge_2.12' for Scala 2.12.6. Compiling...
[info]   Compilation completed in 16.744s.
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
Welcome to Scala 2.12.6 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_172).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> val i=0;
i: Int = 0

scala>
```

Comment: There are no "higher versions". 2.12.6 is the latest release.

Answer (score 0):

See my documentation for runnig Dotty on Windows at the following address:
https://github.com/michelou/dotty-examples/blob/master/README.md